# Closed form and/or approximation for $f_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\cdot i\cdot \log(i)$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, binomial-distribution

Is there any closed form for the expression : $$f_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\cdot i\cdot \log(i)\ ?$$

If not, how to get an approximation?

Comment: I doubt there is an exact closed forn, but there might be a good asymptote. You can use $i\binom{n}{i}=n\binom{n-1}{i-1}$ to simplify it a little, but the result is $n\log M$ for where $M$ is the product of $i^{\binom{n-1}{i-1}}$, which also seems unlikely to have a closed form, in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, ok. I came across this expression while trying to solve some other question. Maybe I should try solving that another way. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: I ended up solving the question I wanted to solve with some other method, but thank you everyone who answered the question! The answers are all different from each other and all are amazing! An upvote to all the answers, but I don't want to accept only one of them! :)

Answer (score 4):

By exploiting Frullani's theorem
$$ \log(k) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-kx}}{x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
we get that:
$$ f_n = n\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left((2^{n-1}-1)e^{-x}-((e^x+1)^{n-1}-1)e^{-nx}\right)\frac{dx}{x}\tag{2}$$
from which:
$$ f_n = n(2^{n-1}-1)\log n+\color{blue}{n\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left[(e^x+1)^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\right]\frac{dx}{x e^{nx}}}. \tag{3} $$
If $a>b>0$ we have $a^n-b^n \leq n(a-b)a^{n-1}$, hence the $\color{blue}{\text{remainder term}}$ in $(3)$ is bounded by:
$$ n(n-1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(e^x+1)^{n-2}(e^x-1)}{x e^{nx}}\,dx\leq n(n-1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(e^x+1)^{n-2}}{e^{(n-1)x}}\,dx\leq n 2^{n-1} $$
hence:
$$ f_n = n 2^{n-1}\left(\log n+O(1)\right) \tag{4}$$
without using any probabilistic argument.

Answer (score 3):

As comments already said, I doubt that a closed form could exist.

However, in terms of approximation, considering the function $$f_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\, i\,\log(i)$$ is is interesting to notice that its logarithm varies almost linearly with $n$ (at least for large values of $n$).

Generating values for $100 \leq n \leq 2000$ (step of $100$), a linear regression leads to $$\log(f_n)\approx 0.694652 \,n+6.23536$$ and a nonlinear regression leads to $$f_n\approx e^{0.693735\,n+7.66555}$$

Extrapolated to $n=3000$, for an "exact" value of $1.35\times 10^{907}$, the simple correlation leads to $1.53\times 10^{907}$. Far from perfection, for sure, but better than nothing to get at least the order of magnitude.

Comment: Both your estimated 0.694652 and 0.693735 are suspiciously close to ln(2) -- for good reasons (see my answer).

Comment: @Did. I noticed that point. Your answer is beautiful !

Answer (score 3):

There is no hope to get exact formulas (since, for example, the logarithms of the prime numbers are linearly independent on the rational numbers). However, one can get rather precise asymptotics of

> $$f_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}k\log k$$

To do so, first note that $$f_n=2^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^n}{n\choose k}k\log k-n\log n=2^nE(B_n\log B_n)-n\log n$$ where $B_n$ is binomial $(n,\frac12)$ with expectation $E(B_n)=\frac{n}2$. The function $x\mapsto x\log x$ is convex hence 
$$f_n\geqslant2^nE(B_n)\log E(B_n)-n\log n=2^{n-1}n\log\left(\tfrac{n}2\right)-n\log n$$
Likewise, $k{n\choose k}=n{n-1\choose k-1}$ hence
$$f_n=2^{n-1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2^{n-1}}{n-1\choose k}\log(k+1)-n\log n=2^{n-1}nE(\log(1+B_{n-1}))-n\log n$$
 where $B_{n-1}$ is binomial $(n-1,\frac12)$ with expectation $E(B_{n-1})=\frac{n-1}2$. The function $x\mapsto \log(1+x)$ is concave hence
$$f_n\leqslant 2^{n-1}n\log(1+E(B_{n-1}))-n\log n=2^{n-1}n\log\left(\tfrac{n+1}2\right)-n\log n$$
To sum up, for every $n$, one has

> $$2^{n-1}n\log(n)\leqslant f_n+2^{n-1}n\log(2)+n\log n\leqslant2^{n-1}n\log(n+1)<2^{n-1}n\log(n)+2^{n-1}$$

which can be simplified into

> $$f_n=2^{n-1}n\log\left(\tfrac{n}2\right)+O(2^n)$$

for an explicit error term $O(2^n)$, which implies $$\log f_n=(n-1)\log2+\log n+\log\log\left(\tfrac{n}2\right)+O\left(\tfrac1{n\log n}\right)$$ for an explicit error term $O\left(\tfrac1{n\log n}\right)$.